# Singular or plural verb with a list of three items

Tags: grammatical-number

I have seen the following sentence in a published book:

*Sentence A*

There **were** a toothbrush, a piece of floss, and a tube of toothpaste.

It sounds wrong to my ear. I would write

*Sentence B*

There **was** a toothbrush, a piece of floss, and a tube of toothpaste.

This is because I believe the verb should agree with the nearest noun, i.e., "a toothbrush".

Is the original sentence correct, or are both versions correct?
Many thanks

Comment: There were several things so you have to use plural verb.

Comment: Answered on [ELL](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/31241/can-we-use-there-is-for-plural-nouns).

Answer (score 3):

Irrespective of the 'official' grammar, I think the OP has a point. I'm willing to bet that 99% of speakers would naturally say 'there was xxx, yyy, zzz' unless xxx is itself plural.

E.g. "There was a cat, a dog and a rabbit in the box". "There were three cats, a dog and a rabbit in the box".

Just because a book says one or the other is right, who has authority to say that the book is right? Eventually usage trumps textbooks.

Comment: Now add about forty years of that train of thought "Just because a book says one or the other is right, who has authority to say that the book is right?" and see WHY so many come here, and I don't mean non-native speakers, I'm talking about the boys and girls, men and women who are partially illiterate in speech and writing because of it. And that's why I've found a home here in this wonderful community.

Answer (score 1):

The second sentence is correct. "As a general rule, use a plural verb with two or more subjects when they are connected by and." [(taken from grammar book)](http://www.grammarbook.com/grammar/subjectVerbAgree.asp)

[This website](http://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/compound-subjects) might provide some further assistance.

Comment: You say "second sentence"which is singular but your quotation says "plural".

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I believe by "second sentence" RE Lavendar was referring to the sentence in the second line, i.e. "There were a toothbrush, a piece of floss, and a tube of toothpaste." I have edited the question and labelled the sentences as Sentence A and Sentence B. As a follow-up question, would Sentence B be incorrect or would it be an acceptable alternative?